# Embedding multi-class applet with .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I have a multi-class applet that has been exported using Eclipse as a .jar file. The jar file is called `chess.jar`, and the class I compiled and ran from in Eclipse is called `Chess.java`, and the binaries are `Chess.class`. The following code is the HTML I am trying to use to embed this applet into my website.

```
<APPLET CODE=Chess.class
ARCHIVE="chess.jar"
WIDTH=700
HEIGHT=700
CODEBASE="mywebsitewherethefilesarebeinghosted.com/"
ALT="Your browser understands the <APPLET> tag but isn't running the applet, for some   reason.">
Your browser is ignoring the <APPLET> tag!
</APPLET>
```

I get the error `ClassNotFoundException Chess.class`

I have done applets before that have only one class successfully [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tinybrozco/) , and I am using almost exactly the same HTML except for the `CODEBASE` and I have added the `ARCHIVE` tag.

As an applet, it has no main class. I am not very familiar with the `MANIFEST.MF` file, and I'm not sure if I need to utilize it for this purpose. My `Chess.class` calls some other classes like `Pawn.class` and `Knight.class` and they are all in `chess.jar`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I created a local HTML file that runs the .jar locally and it runs perfectly.

```
<html>
<applet code=Chess.class 
archive="chess.jar"
width=700 height=700>
</applet> 
</html>
```

Comment: Is your jar file in the same codebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a simple matter of the contents of your HTML. I see you have a second  start tag that I think would be confusing the browser. The browser would think the first one does not have an end tag and that may be the reason it is being ignored. Remove that and try again.

Even if this isn't the problem it's bad practice to leave tags open like that. Your error message should also be a bit more meaningful for poor users who don't know what an applet tag is.

Comment: Thanks a million! I'm not extremely familiar with HTML, and I'm not sure why I did that, but you got it right! Thank you. I will keep your tips in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `CODEBASE` follows `/` as directory separator unlike **`.`** in case of `CODE` attribute
so try replacing your `CODEBASE` value with proper directory structure separated by **/**

check example [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2455252&tstart=0) and [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/exp/ch03_05.htm) also